# set javascript intial variable to data scraped from website

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

I am trying to set a variable in javascript to a value retrieved from another source. For instance, in this case, I have a calculator that is calculating estimated payments.  Currently initial variables are set as follows....

```
// Initial Values<br>

    var data; // To be used by chart<br>
    var homePrice = 250000;<br>
    var downPaymentPercent = 3.5;<br>
    var interestRate = 5.25;<br>
    var user_state = "FL";<br>
```

Two questions I have are...

1.) What would be the easiest way to set the interestRate variable equal to todays 'current rates' as shown by an external website such as...
www.wellsfargo.com/mortgage/rates/purchase-assumptions?prod=1

Also open to learning of a better way if there is a more straight forward method than this

2.) user_state is currently set through this initialisation list, what method would be used to set this state based on a users IP address?

My main interest is in solving question 1 right now, I am curious to question 2, but the first question is more important at the moment.

Thanks!

Comment: use a api......

Comment: I guess you 'the easiest' way is to use an i frame that has display:none as css. Then the element you want to find and use is already on your page :)
But the best way is probably to do it server side.

Comment: u can try with eval(str.replace("<br>", " "));

Comment: Bryro, do you have an example of this or could you explain the implementation of this?  I will look into using an API in the meantime